# Two layers have different zoom level

Tags: wms, google-maps, openlayers-2, zoom

I have added to my OpenLayers-based app two layers. A google maps layer and another WMS layer.

```
physical = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Physical View",
            {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.PHYSICAL,
                numZoomLevels: 21,
                MAX_ZOOM_LEVEL: 21,
                MIN_ZOOM_LEVEL: 6}
    );


ktl = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "Ktl","http://gis.ktimanet.gr/wms/wmsopen/wmsserver.aspx",
        {
            layers: 'KTBASEMAP',
        },
        {
            //format: "image/png",
            //displayOutsideMaxExtent: false,
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        }
    );
```

Both layers are displayed in my app but I face the following zoom-related problem.
When I see the google maps layer the zoom level is different than when I see the WMS layer. I have added two screenshots which illustrate what I describe above.

[image]
[image]

This is quite unexpected as I set the center and zoom of my map as:

```
map.setCenter (lonLat, 1);
```

Is it possible to change the default zoom of a layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For google maps sure you can typically set the intial zoom in mapOptions for creation

```
var mapOptions = {
     zoom: 4,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922)
 };

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
     mapOptions);
```